# Reset password using restful API

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to Create a reset page using restful API. 
I haven't found much info on the internet and I'm probably no using the best method.
 What I'm trying to do is send a code in the email of the user and then after the user typing the code will be decided if he can or cannot update the pass. I can't seem to find a way to pass the value of the code generated on the first request to the second to check if its correct. 
Any help is appreciated.
 Thanks in advance!

```
//ForgotPassword?
app.get('/forgotpassword/:username', function (_req, res) {
    var seq = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 10000).toString().substring(1);
    console.log(seq);

    mysqlConnection.connect(function () {

        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT Email from Customer Where Username = ?', [_req.params.username], (err, results, _fields) => {
            if (!err){
            console.log(results[0].Email);
            var mailOptions = {
                from: 'myemail',
                to: results[0].Email,
                subject: "Password Reset Verification", 
                text: "If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.   CODE: " + seq,
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    //Handle error here
                    res.send('Please try again!');
                } else {
                    
                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                    res.send('Sent!');
                }
            })
        }
             else
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
});
```

````
//CodeRandomCodeFromResetPass
app.get('/reset', function (req, res) {
    var code;
    //if code typed is = to seq sent in the email
    res.send("The code is correct");
});```

//then I'll create a post request that updates the password username from the first get request
````

Comment: In the email you send to the user you need to add the path to your endpoint before the code and then you simply read the code as a get variable, e.g. https://www.[yourdomain].com/code?[yourcode]

Comment: I need to send a link?

Comment: Exactly, otherwise your user won't be able to access the password reset page. You would also need to make that link time sensitive, (e.g. you can store the time you sent it to your db and check against that time when it is visited)

Answer (score 0):

The code sent in email should be store in a table or collection. So code will be store against the email and an expiry time of the code. So in the next phase when the code will pass with an email you can check that this(entered) email should belong to this(entered) code within this(expiry time of code) time frame, so if condition satisfied then requested user can reset/change the password.

Comment: Could you help me with some more specific lines of code?